# How to animate standard progress bar in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I want to show progress bar while the process of server call is going on. The markup is given in LDS but I want an idea for animating it (0%, then 25% and so on) till the response is received and 100% finally. How can this be implemented?

The Lightning Design System markup is:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="slds-progress-bar slds-progress-bar_medium slds-progress-bar_circular" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100" role="progressbar">
  <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 100%</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a merge field to show the percentage:

```
<aura:attribute name="percentDone" type="Integer" default="0" />

<div data-reactroot="" class="slds-progress-bar slds-progress-bar_medium slds-progress-bar_circular" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="{!v.percentDone}" role="progressbar">
  <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="{!'width:'+v.percentDone+'%'}">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: {!v.percentDone}%</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

From there, you can then set the percent as appropriate in your controller:

```
component.set("v.percentDone", 50); // sets process to 50% done.
```

Comment: yes I have done something of the sort already, just that I wanted to show it increasing as the backend process is progressing. I have updated my code for that.

Comment: @Sarang If it's just a single response, a progress bar is probably deceptive. After all, you have no idea what the progress is until it's done. You're probably better off showing a [spinner](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_spinner.htm) instead.

Comment: Yes I agree. Spinner is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var progress = <whatever_is_the_progress>;
document.getElementsByClassName('slds-progress-bar__value')[0].style.width = progress + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Markup:

```
<!--SOME MARKUP-->
<lightning:layoutItem class="slds-progress-bar slds-progress-bar_medium .slds-progress-bar_circular"> 
                    <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="{!('width: ' + v.barWidth + ';')}">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 100%</span>
                    </span>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

> Helper:

```
/*Method for calling service for uploading file*/
uploadAttachment : function(component, helper, file){
    /*Some Code before service call*/

    /*Call back method after receiving service response*/
    service.uploadAttachment(request, function(response) {
        //Some Other Code

        /*When response is received, set the width to 100% and hide the modal/window and exit.*/
               component.set('v.barWidth','100%');
               window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                helper.hideModal(component, event, helper);
            }), 1000);
        }

        /*Shows the animation in progress bar*/
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            component.set('v.barWidth','50%');
            window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                    component.set('v.barWidth','75%');
                    window.setTimeout(
                        $A.getCallback(function() {
                            component.set('v.barWidth','85%');
                        }), 500
                    );
                }), 500
            );
        }), 500
    );
},
```